# Re-stream h.246 video

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, vlc

I have a video from a web cam that is streaming h.264 video via the web (according to Wireshark, it is using tcp over port 9000).

I've tried opening it in VLC player, but have been unsuccessful. Perhaps I'm using the wrong command, or VLC can't read raw h.264?

How do I go about re-streaming the raw h.264 to... lets say mp4?

I've seen mentions of using VLC (server) to convert it, but I can't find the proper documentation.  I assume it's something along the lines of

```
vlc -vvv tcp://my_ip:9000 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=100}:standard{access=http,mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=:9090}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Even a link to the proper documentation...  Ultimately, I would like to have the re-streaming video viewable via html5 video tag.

Answer (score 0):

Most IP cameras use rtsp to initiate the mpeg stream. You'll need the complete url for the stream you want. This should all be documented on the camera manufacturer's web site. The info you need is typically in the developer's section.

For example, for an Axis 207 it is:
rtsp://192.168.1.1/mpeg4/media.amp